# Days between dates calculation

Tags: datetime, stata

I imported date variables as strings from SQL (`date1`) into Stata and then created a new date variable (`date2`) like this:

```
gen double date2 = clock(date1, "YMDhms")
format date2 %tc
```

However, now I want to calculate the number of days between two dates (`date3-date2`), formatted as above, but I can't seem to do it.

I don't care about the hms, so perhaps I should strip that out first? And then deconstruct the date into YYYY MM DD as separate variables? Nothing I seems to do is working right now.

Comment: You should just be able to convert to a Stata date using `daily()`, and then subtract the two. Directly from `help datetime` you can see `date2 - date1 = days between date1 and date2`. The same can be said for datetimes to get milliseconds between two datetimes, weeks between week1 and week2, months, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like by dates you actually mean timestamp (aka datetime) variables. In my experience, there's usually no need to cast dates/timestamps as strings since ODBC and Stata will handle the conversion to SIF td/tc formats nicely.

But perhaps you exported to a text file and then read in the data instead. Here are a couple solutions.

tc timestamps are in milliseconds since 01jan1960 00:00:00.000, assuming 1000*60*60*24=86,400 seconds/day (that is, ignoring leap seconds). This means that you need to divide your difference by that number to get elapsed days.

For example, 2016 was a leap year:

```
. display (tc(01jan2017 00:00:00) - tc(01jan2016 00:00:00))/(1000*60*60*24)
366
```

You can also use the `dofc()` function to make dates out of timestamps and omit the division:

```
. display (dofc(tc(01jan2018 00:00:00)) - dofc(tc(01jan2016 00:00:00)))
731
```

2017 is not a leap year, so 366 + 365 = 731 days.

You can use `generate` with all these functions, though `display` is often easier for debugging initial attempts.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. It turns out it was in milliseconds so I needed to divide by 86,400,000.